# Getting array values from an imploded function

Tags: php

so I have this variable **$_GET** which receives the value such as

```
set=QnVzaW5lc3M=|RmluYW5jZQ==
```

The values are base64 enconded using base64_encode() and then separated by a delimiter '**|**'. I'm using implode function to generate the value of the set variable.

Now, the question is, how can I get the values from the set variable into an array and base64 decode them as well ?

Any suggestions are welcome.
I tried this :-

```
$test = array();
$test = explode('|', $_GET['set']);
var_dump($test);
```

This throws the value which is not usable.
But this made no difference.

Comment: `explode` and `base64_decode`? I wonder why you are having problems if you managed to do it the one way

Comment: @knittl
I tried this :- echo explode('|', $_GET['set']); , but this did not help me.

Comment: Well yes, that will only output `Array`, since you cannot echo arrays directly in php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745338/how-to-convert-base64-string-to-binary-array-using-php   http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$data = 'QnVzaW5lc3M=|RmluYW5jZQ==';
$result = array_map(
    'base64_decode',
    explode('|', $data)
);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work using `foreach`:

```
// Set the test data.
$test_data = 'QnVzaW5lc3M=|RmluYW5jZQ==';

// Explode the test data into an array.
$test_array = explode('|', $test_data);

// Roll through the test array & set final values.
$final_values = array();
foreach ($test_array as $test_value) {
  $final_values[] = base64_decode($test_value);
}

// Dump the output for debugging.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($final_values);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Business
    [1] => Finance
)
```